# How to write custom DGML properties

Tags: c#, xml, dgml

I have got the latest DGML [schema](http://schemas.microsoft.com/vs/2009/dgml/) and generated a set of c# classes via xsd.exe but I can't see how to programatically add custom properties to a node.

The XML would look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DirectedGraph xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vs/2009/dgml">
  <Nodes>
    <Node Id="_85" Label="MyNode" CustomProperty="XXX" />
  </Nodes>
  <Properties>
    <Property Id="CustomProperty" Label="YYY" Group="ZZZ" />
  </Properties>
</DirectedGraph>
```

How do I add `CustomProperty` attributes to the `Node`?

Comment: There is no custom property in a Node.  You could give it a Group attribute and then use the same Group in the Property node.

Comment: There IS a custom property.  If you defined a property, then whatever the value of the `Id` field is, becomes a custom property in the `Node`, as shown in the example above.

Comment: I will double check

Comment: I did not see in the schema any way of adding a custom property.  It is a complicated schema and could of miss the option or you may be using a different version of the schema then the link you provided.

Comment: See sample at msdn.  I think CustomProperty should be Category : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/directed-graph-markup-language-dgml-reference?view=vs-2015

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely defined custom properties, but they are "metadata" not something you will see on the graph itself.  They contain type information about the property which can affect how the  respond to those values.  Here's an example.  If you select the Link with the custom Priority property the F4 property window will show the metadata about that property.

```
<DirectedGraph xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vs/2009/dgml">
  <Nodes>
    <Node Id="Banana" UseManualLocation="True" />
    <Node Id="Test" UseManualLocation="True" />
  </Nodes>
  <Links>
    <Link Source="Test" Target="Banana" Priority="10"/>
    <Link Source="Test" Target="Green" />
  </Links>
  <Properties>
    <Property Id="Bounds" DataType="System.Windows.Rect" />
    <Property Id="UseManualLocation" DataType="System.Boolean" />
    <Property Id="Priority" DataType="System.Double"  
              Label="Poobar" Group="Metrics" 
              Description="A fun new property"/>
  </Properties>
  <Styles>
    <Style TargetType="Link">
      <Setter Property="Weight" Expression="Priority * 3" />
    </Style>
  </Styles>
</DirectedGraph>
```

Comment: Thanks @chris, but this doesn't tell me how to add them via the classes generated from schema, does it?

Comment: Ah, I assume you are using Microsoft.VisualStudio.GraphModel.dll, in that case see the Graph Metadata information in this spec: https://lovettchris.github.io/posts/GraphModel/